# How do I write a function that return the the first number with highest frequency(mode)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mode

I am solving a problem which asks me to return the number with the highest frequency(mode). For example, if arr contains **[3, 9, 3, 1, 6]** the output should be **3**. If there is more than one mode, I want to return the one that appeared first. **[6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5]** should return **6** because it appeared first. If there is no mode, I want to return **0**. The array will not be empty. I am new to algorithms, please suggest a simpler solution for me.

```
function Mode(arr) { 
  const arrayObject = {};
 
  arr.forEach(arr => {
      if(!arrayObject[arr]) {
          arrayObject[arr] = 1
        //   console.log(arrayObject)
      } else if(arrayObject[arr]){
          arrayObject[arr] += 1
        //   console.log(arrayObject)
      }
  })
  console.log(arrayObject) // { '3': 2, '5': 2, '6': 2 } array keys are automatically sorted in ascending other.This could be the problem but I don't know how to unsort the arrays//
  
  let highestValueKey = 0;
  let highestValue = 0
  
  for(let key in arrayObject) {
        const value = arrayObject[key]
        if(value > highestValue) {
          highestValue = value
          highestValueKey = key   
      }
      
  }
     return Number(highestValueKey)
 
}
console.log(Mode([6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5])) // 3 instead of 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of both count AND when it was first seen.

```
function mode (arr) {
    const countSeen = {};
    const firstSeen = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let elem = arr[i];
        if (! countSeen[elem]) {
            countSeen[elem] = 1;
            firstSeen[elem] = i;
        }
        else {
            countSeen[elem]++;
        }
    }

    let mostSeenCount = 0;
    let mostSeenValue = null;
    for (let elem of Object.keys(countSeen)) {
        if (mostSeenCount < countSeen[elem] ||
            (mostSeenCount == countSeen[elem] && firstSeen[elem] < firstSeen[mostSeenValue])
        ) {
            mostSeenCount = countSeen[elem];
            mostSeenValue = elem;
        }
    }

    return mostSeenValue;
}

console.log(mode([5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count the number of occurrences, then choose the max from there.

```js
function mode(arr) {
  const counts = arr.reduce((result, value, index) => {
    // result is the object we're building up.
    // value is the current item from the array.
    // index is value's position within the array
    
    // if result[value] doesn't already exist, create it
    result[value] = (result[value] || { index, value, count: 0 });
    
    // increment the 'count' for this value
    result[value].count++;
    
    // return the updated result
    return result;
  }, {});
  
  // sort the entries by count in descending order, then by index
  // ascending such that sorted[0] will be the entry with the highest
  // count, and lowest index if more that one element has the same count
  const sorted = Object.values(counts)
    .sort((
      {count: ca, index: ia},
      {count: cz, index: iz}
    ) => (cz - ca) || (ia - iz));
  
  // then return that entry's value
  return sorted[0].value;
}

console.log(mode([6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5])) // 6
console.log(mode([3, 9, 3, 1, 6])) // 3
console.log(mode([3, 9, 3, 6, 1, 9, 9])) // 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map whose keys are the array values, and the corresponding Map value is the frequency count:

- Create the map and initialise the counts with 0
- Increment the count as each input value is visited.
- Use `Math.max` to get the greatest count from that map
- Iterate the map to find the first count that matches that maximum

As Map entries are iterated in insertion order, the correct key will be identified in the last step.

```js
function mode(arr) {
    const counts = new Map(arr.map(i => [i, 0]));
    for (const i of arr) counts.set(i, counts.get(i) + 1);
    const maxCount = Math.max(...counts.values());
    for (const [i, count] of counts) {
        if (count == maxCount) return i;
    }
}

console.log(mode([3, 9, 3, 1, 6])); // 3
console.log(mode([6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5])); // 6
console.log(mode([3, 9, 3, 6, 1, 9, 9])); // 9
console.log(mode([5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5])); // 5
```

Comment: can you please explain more on your last statement? ''As Map entries are iterated in insertion order, the correct key will be identified in the last step''

Comment: If there is a tie, the one that came first in the input will als the first one encountered in the map having that frequency.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand, maybe I will have to do further research. Your code is more readable and that's why I want to focus on it more. I have one more question; when you increment the count with the for loop in the second line - `for (const i of arr) counts.set(i, counts.get(i) + 1);` I expect the **counts.get(i) + 1** to treated as value + 1, for instance; 3 + 1 = 4,  9 + 1 = 10. Can you please explain this better